# Laptop recommendation

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, memory

Recommend a laptop which is portable, good display, backlit and ergonomic keyboard in a price range less than 1500$. It should have i7 quad core or higher, 8gb or 16gb ram, 256 gb ssd or more, touchpad should be as large as possible. Companies preferred : Dell, HP, Apple, Lenovo and maybe asus. Decent graphic card for ml and dl purposes is good but it should not hinder portability.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Dell G7 7588 is good to you.
Product Specification - Dell G7 7588

KEY SPECIFICATIONS:

- Display: 15.6" Anti-Glare LED Back-lit Display (1920x1080)
- Processor:8th Generation Intel Core i7-8750H (9MB Cache, 2.2 GHz up to 4.1 GHz)
- Memory: 16GB DDR4 RAM
- Hard drive size: 256GB Solid State Drive + 1TB Hard Drive
- Operating system: Windows 10 Home, 64-bit
- Video:  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 -6GB with Max-Q
- Audio: Waves MaxxAudio
- Ports: 3 x USB Type-A, 1 x USB 3.1 Type-C, 1 x HDMI, Headphone + Microphone Combo Jack
- Wireless: WiFi 802.11AC, Bluetooth
- Dimensions: 15.3 x 0.93 x 10.8"
- Features: Built-in Webcam
- Weight: 5.07 lbs

Check amazon website for more information [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07FLPG56B/ref=psdc_13896615011_t1_B07DTJW6K3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FLPG56B)

Comment: Yes, but the weight is 5.8 pounds. I require no more weight than 4 pounds